# More concise Scala extractor definition syntax

Tags: scala, pattern-matching

Extractors can be an incredibly useful way to reduce duplication in pattern matching code, however, often the logic contained in them is just a simple one-line pattern that needed to be DRYed out from the code, for example, I had a recurring pattern of `Person(_, _, Some(Position(_, Some(company))))`, so I came up with this extractor:

```scala
object EmployedAt {
  def unapply(x: Person): Option[Company] = x match {
    case Person(_, _, Some(Position(_, company))) => company
    case _ => None
  }
}
```

which I could then use like this:

```scala
val companies = people.collect { case EmployedAt(c) => c }.distinct

def numEmployees(company: Company) =
  people.collect { case EmployedAt(`company`) => }.size

people.collect { case p @ EmployedAt(c) if numEmployees(c) >= 2 => (p, c) }
```

etc — all very nice, concise and readable... except for the extractor implementation itself. The problem I'm seeing is that, ultimately, the extractor just boils down to the 1st `case` statement, and the rest is just boilerplate. Instead, I think the following would be much more desirable for defining simple (possibly one-off or twice-off) extractors:

```scala
def EmployedAt(x: Person): Company = {
  case Person(_, _, Some(Position(_, Some(company)))) => company
}
```

...which is 2 full lines instead of 4.

— how would I go about DRYing up the boilerplate to come to something as concise as the above?

Answer (score 4):

I immediately started playing around with potential solutions and I think I've come to quite a nice one, which, in addition to allowing the definition of extractors without the `object`+`unapply`+`Option[T]`+`case _ => None` boilerplate, also makes it immediately obvious to the reader that a given function is an extractor, as well as statically marking it as an `Extractor`:

```
trait Extractor[T, U] { def unapply(x: T): Option[U] }
object Extractor {
  def apply[T, U](f: PartialFunction[T, U]) = new Extractor[T, U] {
    def unapply(x: T) = f.lift(x)
  }
}

val EmployedAt = Extractor[Person, Company] {
  case Person(_, _, Some(Position(_, Some(company)))) => company
}
```

I did not have the intention to immediately answer my own question but this is how it turned out. I'm still open to criticism and other suggestions from potentially more competent Scala community members! :)